# Blacklist/whitelist for XSS

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I need to implement XSS defence and I have troubles with it.
I read this cheatsheet
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html
There are a lot of valuable information, but Its fairly difficult for me to implement this.
I understand, you need to escape untrusted data, I already implemented it in my application, but I need to also implement some kind of blacklist/whitelist, right? What is allowed in the data and what is not allowed.
I tried to use this code on my server side (which is java), but I would need to something similiar on the front-end side. I am using core javascript and jquery

1. Is it a good approach?
2. Is there any library which could help me to build blacklist/whitelist?
3. Or how can I make sure that escaped data does not contain for example javascript: etc?
4. I found this library for escaping characters. 
   https://github.com/YahooArchive/xss-filters/wiki Is it ok to use it?

   ```
       // Avoid anything between script tags
       Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Avoid anything in a src='...' type of expression
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Remove any lonesome </script> tag
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Remove any lonesome <script ...> tag
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Avoid eval(...) expressions
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Avoid expression(...) expressions
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Avoid javascript:... expressions
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Avoid vbscript:... expressions
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       // Avoid onload= expressions
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
   ```

Comment: "*I need to also implement some kind of blacklist/whitelist*" - no, escaping values is enough in general. It only becomes difficult if your values are not just plain data, but you want to allow untrusted data to affect your page structure, or even create (parts of) markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blacklists don't really work. They can only cover attacks that match a pattern that the programmer has already thought of, but there are new variations and techniques found all the time. See [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) for example.

Browsers like Chrome have made a big effort to try to detect XSS with their filters but even then they're now planning on removing it because it was full of holes and blocked legitimate input ([Google to remove Chrome's built-in XSS protection](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-to-remove-chromes-built-in-xss-protection-xss-auditor/))

The filters you've found are particularly bad. There are obvious omissions, like it looks for `onload` but not `onmouseover`. It doesn't deal with nested values, so `<vbscript:script>alert(1)</scriptvbscript:>` becomes `<script>alert(1)</script>`. There are also many types of XSS attack these kind of filters can't detect like if multiple parameters are used together.

Instead, focus on the OWASP Rules on that cheatsheet. Here, there are some uses of whitelists but they are easier to implement because they're looking for specific known values. So Rule #7 (Avoid JavaScript URLs), can be implemented by looking for a 'http:' or 'https:' at the beginning of any URL you're outputting. Rule #6 (Sanitize HTML Markup) can be implemented with another library which is configured to only allow specific tags and values.

The Yahoo library looks reasonable enough for escaping, but it looks like it's not maintained anymore. Their approach with escaping the minimum possible characters for performance reasons requires more methods that some other libraries and you need to be more careful to use the exact right method for each context (like `inSingleQuotedAttr` vs `inDoubleQuotedAttr`). Instead, I'd use a library that escapes at least `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, `'` for their HTML escaping and then a lot of these methods could be merged together.

With JavaScript, most modern templating languages will escape values by default, or you can stick to the text based DOM methods like `$().attr()` and `$().text()` instead of `$().html()`, then there's not as much of a need for an external escaping library.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, I should create method that escapes &, <, >, ", ' which will be called on the result of that yahoo library function (the correct type)? Is it not sufficient to do escaping only with these methods and why not please? I would basically use only inHTMLData() and inDoubleQuotedAttr and inUrlFragmentComponent() methods. I do not work with untrusted HTML code/or css code.

Comment: @Arthonius The yahoo library functions should be fine by themselves. A html escape function (plus url component escape function) is just a possible alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can add text escaping to block **reflected** XSS attacks, but you should really consider the implementation of security headers on your web server to block **stored** XSS attacks.

Check out the [CSP Security Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) for a detailed explanation and documentation on how to implement it. If you use something like NGINX it's pretty easy to implement.

If you have any doubt on the difference between this XSS attacks please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This may help on frontend, you can use this on backend as well.

```
String.prototype.preventXss = function () {
  const blackList = /['</>']/g;
  return this.replace(blackList, '');
};

let mystring = '<h1>';
console.log(mystring.preventXss());
```